# Phpmyadmin access denied due to accidentally lock account

Tags: mysql, xampp, phpmyadmin

Hello my Xampp was working and I access also the phpmyadmin in website, at first I was able to access the PhpMyAdmin site when I was there I accidentally lock the local host after that I was not be able to access it again I tried so many ways to fix that but unfortunately I did not fix it I don't know you could help me with that but i'm trying, I think I click "user" in phpmyadmin site and I saw the "root" which is the local host and I accidentally click the lock account, after that I didn't access it again please help me that is my first time using phpmyadmin, i've watched a lot of tutorials but i didn't found exactly the tutorials that I was looking for, I don't know how to fix it, please help.

Comment: You could help us by [editing](https://superuser.com/posts/1722732/edit) your question and telling what exactly you have tried so far

Comment: Please, add that information to your question, not as a comment. Readers must be able to get a clear picture of your problem without having to dig through the comments. Also, tell us what you tried to fix it (you said you tried many things).

Comment: Check the answers in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530862/added-password-to-root-locked-out-of-phpmyadmin),

Comment: Maybe I can uninstall it and do re-installation does it work? what do you think guys?

Comment: @SANTIAGOBENJOMENDOZA - What exactly are you going to reinstall?  If the only elevated privileged account you have is `root`, then your only choice, is to start completely over with the database.  Reinstalling MySQL (through Xampp ) will not resolve your problem.  Even if it did you would be wiping the database in the process, would is effetely, what you need to do since you have no user who can access the database.

Comment: What could i do? :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem,  in XAMPP  open Apache - config  then  in phpMyAdmin(config.inc.php)  change  $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';  instead of "root"  put another user  "pma" work for me,  then unlock the account,   then put the config.inc.php   with the user "root" again.   that works for me.